# How do I work on my react-native (Android 4.4) app where there's no wifi?

Tags: android, react-native

I've got my rooted Android 4.4 device USB-plugged into my Windows laptop, and I can develop fine when they're on the same wifi network. As soon as I turn Wifi off on the tablet, it can't receive updates.

I don't need hot reloading, I just want to be able to update this app once or twice without a network.

Don't say `adb reverse`, 'cause it only works on Android 5+.

Answer (score 1):

Android port forwarding can connect via USB, i have used in kit kat

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/191930/Android-Usb-Port-Forwarding

Answer (score 0):

If you have good internet connection, you can use `ngrok` and expose the port number `8081`.

Comment: I guess I should have specified -- no internet at all.